# Finding the intersection of a plane and a line without libraries

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, intersection, plane

Me and my friend are trying to make a 3D renderer without external libraries.
We are trying to find the plane with the direction the User looking at as a normal vector and position of the User translated in the direction of the normal vector. So the plane Will always be in frot of the User with some distance.
We planned to define a line from the vertecies of the shape to the User and find the intersection with the plane and draw the shape.

And we are avoiding to use any libraries becouse it is something of a challenge to try to make it ourselfes.

But We were not able to define the plane or line since it would be something like;
3x+4z=7y

And We dont know how can We communicate that to Python.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how your plane is defined.
If you have normal vector `n` and some point `p` in plane, you can get free coefficient of generap plane equation (`d`) substituting `p` coordinates into this:

```
d = nx * px + nx * py + nz * pz
```

Now plane equation is

```
nx * x + nx * y + nz * z - d = 0
```

Define line using parametric equation

```
x = x0 + dx * t
y = y0 + dy * t
z = z0 + dz * t
```

where `(x0,y0,z0)` is some point at the line and `(dx,dy,dz)` is direction vector (if you have another point at the line, than `dx=x1-x0` and so on)

Now substitute these expressions into plane equation and solve equation for unknown `t`, then get `x,y,z`  - intersection point.

Nnote that sometimes equation has no solution - when line is parallel to the plane, or infinite number of solutions - when line lies in the plane.